# Prove the existence of an entire function satisfying these conditions

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity, entire-functions

This question was asked in an assignment that I am trying to solve.

> Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ be continuous. Then prove the existence of an entire function $g$ such that $|f(x)-g(x)|< 1$ for all  $x\in  \mathbb{R}$.

I am sorry to say but for this question, I won't be able to provide any attempt as I don't know how to use the definition of continuity to prove the existence of $g.$

For background: have done a course in complex analysis, but that was marred due to a terrible instructor. I am not good at doing problems and hence trying.

Comment: Unless you have written the problem incorrectly, then you don't need to know any complex analysis for this problem. In fact you don't even need to know anything about continuity.

Comment: @Daron  An analytic function is infinitely many times differentiable. How are you sure that in proving entire , no complex analysis is needed? Also , Problem is written right.

Comment: That is a result from T. Carleman, you can find it for example here: https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.mmj/1031710533.

Comment: @ Ben: What is the domain of $g$?

Comment: @Daron well it's entire so domain is $\mathbb{C}$ but Inequality is to be proved on $\mathbb{R}$. I think there is a lot of difference in these two

Comment: @You should make that obvious in the question.